# What song are these lyrics from?

Tags: computer-puzzle, music

```
function me(something){
    something++;
}

something != same;
```

Can you guess the song based on the lyrics above?

Comment: "Call me maybe"?

Comment: Nope.  I will give the genre after a while if nobody has solved it.

Comment: Okay, so this was my first puzzle. I like the concept but feel the execution was pretty lame. I tried to keep it simple but mistakenly made it too easy as well. If anyone has any suggestions for improvement, I'll gladly listen.

Comment: Personally, I liked this one.  I actually laughed, aloud, when I saw what the lyrics were that matched up.

Comment: If you feel that the execution is lame, try porting it to another platform... \*facepalm\*

Comment: @Daniel I'm not exactly a programming **expert** per se, but I know PHP best, jQuery/Javascript second, and I was trying to keep it fairly generic.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Thanks much. :)  I'd been seeing the influx of program puzzles lately and I'm a musical nerd, so this started bouncing around my head before long.

Comment: Oh, I know.  I have a complex one in mind, but I haven't thought of a good way to present it where it couldn't be solved by just plugging it into an IDE.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Generic pseudocode FTW! :D I'm happy to help implement if you'd like.

Comment: Considered it, but I don't want the puzzle to take people 6 months to solve.  Hahahaha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The song is

> Defying Gravity

because of the lyrics

> Something has changed within me.  Something is not the same.

Comment: Nice. I didn't expect it to happen that quick.